# How can I initialize a large static read-only dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have some dictionaries in my game library. Here's an example of one: https://github.com/Kermalis/PokemonBattleEngine/blob/60db53fd2c1aedfa22cf9f9fec8973983249b921/PokemonBattleEngine/Data/PokemonData_Data.cs

These dictionaries must be available at all times that they are required, and read-only, so I made a static ReadOnlyDictionary that solves both of those problems. The new problem is when this specific dictionary is first accessed, the programs will climb up to 650MB of memory and then back down to normal (which also takes quite a while), and in Xamarin, the app refuses to initialize the static class because "the program is too complex" (I assume the compiled bytecode is unable to work well).

What is the logical approach here? I cannot find good recommendations for this specific use-case. Should I ditch this for some databases (will that work well on mobile)? Should I be using a HashTable (how would it be read-only)? Should I just split the static constructor up into multiple methods that add, for example, 25 entries at a time with the garbage collector running between each method? These are ideas I have had but I am not sure which to go with because I am no expert. I am developing this library only because it is a huge learning experience, and I would love to know the best approach here in case I also run into this issue in a much more meaningful situation when I am out of college.

Comment: How about making resource file for each pokemon data and instead of accessing it via dictionary you just load required resource instead? It seems like huge overhead to load data about every single pokemon when in fact you might need just 5 of them.

Comment: I'd be looking to persist this volume of data in Sqlite, or similar. I haven't done any Xamarin / UWP development for a couple of years but Akavache was a decent solution at the time.

Comment: Until very recently there were only a handful of Pokémon data in this dictionary, which is why the overhead issue wasn't there before.
With resources, how would I have the data be similar to the object it is now? The object looks like this: https://github.com/Kermalis/PokemonBattleEngine/blob/60db53fd2c1aedfa22cf9f9fec8973983249b921/PokemonBattleEngine/Data/PokemonData.cs

Comment: @Kermalis Use Sqlite as your store

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be static? I don't see a compelling reason. Your problem will be solved if you drop the static keyword, and the computer running this program has sufficient memory.

Comment: It needs to be static because the Pokémons' data are constant, and you are not going to create any. The library itself uses each key's data and all other clients as well whenever they want to, by "PBEPokemonData pData = PBEPokemonData.Data[PBESpecies.Bulbasaur];" for example. This is why I proposed the other ideas I had since they can also treat each species as constant information.

Answer (score 0):

I will be using sqlite databases where the primary key is the Pokémon species ID and the table has JSON which will be deserialized. I may decide to have it cachable, but I am unsure now, since I do not know the speed this will run at.